# Is there a non-trivial, exact analytic (symbolic) conformal map from some polygon to some rectangle?

Tags: polygons, conformal-maps

I'm looking for any example of a conformal map $m: P \to Q$ where $P$ is some polygon of at least $4$ sides, $Q$ is a rectangle, and and $m$ is not linear (so $P$ and $Q$ are not merely scaled, rotated, & translated copies of each other).  FWIW, $Q$ must in general depend on $P$, which is why I'm not specifying $Q$ further here.

1. I don't care how many sides $P$ has for this example -- I want it in order to validate some more general work.  (Especially helpful if the number of sides is "small", say $< 7$ or even $10$.  Even better if it has $4$ sides [not all right angles], but that's not necessary.)
2. I understand that $m$ won't be unique.  I'm just looking for ANY such $m$.
3. Crucially, I need $m$ to be exact, symbolic, constructed, and fully "worked out".  By that, I mean no limits, no implicit functions (or ones with only an existence proof but no construction), no indefinite unevaluated integrals, etc.  I am flexible in what class of functions is used to express $m$, but think of those in, say, Abramowitz & Stegun, or implemented in the core of MATLAB.  E.g., elementary, incomplete beta, Bessel, and elliptic-integral functions are all fine.

The reason I phrase #3 that way is that I want to be able to inspect m, look at its derivatives, etc., which will be opaque  if the function is not explicitly written in terms of such functions.  What makes the conditions of #3 useful for that is that those functions (a) satisfy various analytic and algebraic relations, with published theorems behind them, and (b) have already been implemented in code according to established standards of accuracy and numerical stability (something which might not automatically be true of their inverses, BTW).

Comment: This should be able to be worked out by pairing a Schwartz-Christoffel map (which conformally maps the upper half plane onto a regular $n$-sided polygon) with its own inverse, which is conformal. The only issue is with your condition 3, but I believe (from [this at least](https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/8761/1/Willem_Hendriks_WB_2009.pdf)) the inverse of a Schwartz-Christoffel map is an elliptic function, which you allow.

Comment: Alas, this is precisely what we've done.  What we want is *someone else's* (presumably published) derivation.  FWIW, knowing (only) of the existence of an inverse is what I mean by "an existence proof (but no construction)".  I acknowledge that #3 is tricky, but it's the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Map both your polygon and rectangle on the disk, and take a composition. This is done by Christoffel-Schwarz formula. Cristoffel-Schwarz formula is completely "explicit" (whatever this word could exactly mean), for triangles, and also sufficiently "explicit" for rectangles (using elliptic integrals.)

Comment: Thanks.  Yup, we're already there.  But see my above comment: "explicit" is the whole problem at this stage.  The general theorems to produce the map (like C-S) aren't sufficient "explicit" to be useful.  At least, we haven't either seen or constructed an example that is explicit according to the #3 criteria (even though we use those elliptic integrals freely).

Comment: What you are asking in 3 is not possible: "no limits" means "no integrals", "no series", since the definition of integral involves a limit. So you prohibit even elementary functions like $e^z$ (its definition involves la limit!). If only arithmetic and extraction of roots is involved, then the function will be algebraic, while it is known that the conformal map of a polygon is not algebraic.

Comment: The absence of limits is only about the *expressions*, not the path to create them.  (I explicitly allowed all elementary functions, among many others, so I'm not restricting to algebraic functions alone.)

Comment: Perhaps I can clarify: I am looking for a PUBLISHED non-trivial, exact analytic (symbolic) conformal map from some polygon to some rectangle.  If there is one, then almost certainly my constraints for #3 will have been met.  Or at least it will be clear how to meet them, or that they cannot be met.

Comment: Published conformal map is the Christoffel-Schwarz map. It does not meet your constraint 3, and a map meeting this constraint does not exist. Concerning your other requirements: "exact", "analytic", "symbolic", it is not clear what these words exactly mean, and you have to define them. S-C map is certainly analytic in the common sense of this word, but you probably mean something else.

Comment: The C-S map is the content of a general theorem.  It is not a *specific* map, nor is it particularized to the polygon situation I described.  I have not been able to find any such specific map published anywhere -- hence my hope that someone here knows otherwise.  For all I know, someone published one in the 1890s, or the 1930s.  But I don't have good search capabilities for such papers or books, so I'm asking the much broader population here for anything they might have seen.

Comment: BTW, at least one map meeting my constraint #3 obviously exists: the trivial map(s) from a rectangle to any other rectangle of the same aspect ratio.  (This violates my constraint #1 but *not* #3.)  So, until proven otherwise, I do not accept that no such map is even *possible*.